# Do you need = new String[] in array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] months = {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(months));
```

---

```
String[] months = new String[] {"January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(months));
```

These two codes gave the same result. So I'm wondering which is an appropriate way to write.

Comment: @NicholasK Please don't add unrelated tags. It is completely irrelevant what type of Array OP uses here.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog This question is not about using `new` for strings. It's about using `new` for arrays.

Comment: @khelwood one applies to the other. he just needs to read it and think about it a bit

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] arr = { "Alpha", "Beta" };
```

and

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "Alpha", "Beta" };
```

do exactly the same thing. The first is a shortcut which is allowed when you are declaring an array variable and initialising it in the same line.

However, in other cases, you must use `new String[]` to declare the type of the array you are creating.

```
String[] arr;
arr = { "Alpha", "Beta" }; // this will not compile
arr = new String[] { "Alpha", "Beta" }; // this will compile
```